# Xcode Textfield Above Sections in TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a TableViewController with two sections and I'm trying to insert a textfield to be above the sections with no success.

Someone knows how can I do it without changing to UIViewController and add UITableView?

[image: my TableViewController:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use a `UITableViewController` then you can put the text field in its own section containing one row. The text field can be put in that row's table view cell.

You'll need to adjust all of the table view data source and delegate methods to deal with the extra section.

Comment: Thanks :) I will do that